# What is the right jquery selector to read an input text in the same html table row?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<table>
        <tr>
             <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myTextA" />
             </td>
             <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myTextB" />
             </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myText" />
                  <span class="mySpan"></span>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myTextA" />
             </td>
             <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myTextB" />
             </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myText" />
                  <span class="mySpan"></span>
             </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myTextA" />
             </td>
             <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myTextB" />
             </td>
              <td>
                  <input type="text" class="myText" />

                  <span class="mySpan"></span>
             </td>
        </tr>

      </table>
```

I have the following jquery  where i am looping through the class selector and i need to reference another textbox in the same row and get the val of that other textbox:

```
 $('.myText').each(function (index, data) 
 {
    $(data).val("Test");
    //I now need to reference the val() of the "myTextA" that is in the same row as the item
 });
```

How can i reference this inside this loop to grab to respective input text in the same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `tr` then use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to target the desired `input` element

```
$('.myText').each(function (index, data) {
    $(data).val("Test");
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.myTextA').val("Test 2");
    //I now need to reference the val() of the "myTextA" that is in the same row as the item
});
```

Demo:

```js
$('.myText').val(function (i) {
    return i;
})
$('.myText').each(function (index, data) {
  //value from .myText is copied to .myTextA, just to demonstrate that the element is read
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.myTextA').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myTextA" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myTextB" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myText" /> <span class="mySpan"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myTextA" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myTextB" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myText" /> <span class="mySpan"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myTextA" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myTextB" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="myText" /> <span class="mySpan"></span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I want to just read the val() of "myTextA" (not change it).  does find() return an array or a single element?  can I simply do find().val() as that doesn't seem to work . .

Comment: @leora `.find()` returns a set of elements, it may be 1 or more elements based on how many elements with the given selector is present in the given context... in your case it will return only one element

Comment: @leora `$(this).closest('tr').find('.myTextA')` will return the target element, you can do whatever you want to do with it(read/write value)

Comment: @leora If you can go through the [traversal api](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) methods...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.myTextA').val();
```

This should return the value of myTextA within the same row

Comment: I am looping through myText and I need to find the value of "myTextA"